# Navigation Bar disappearing when tapping done from youtube embedded player (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, youtube-api, ytplayerview

I have a Youtube embedded player in one of the views of my app. If I exit playback in landscape mode, the navigation bar shrinks to half its size throughout the app. The app is set to portrait mode by default.

[Here is the shrunken navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehz7M.png)

The navigation bar, however remains fine if I tap done in portrait.
How can I solve this problem?

EDIT: The playerView code:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var playerView: YTPlayerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(passVideoId)
    playerView.loadWithVideoId(passVideoId)

}
```

passVideoId is the video id passed on from the previous view.

Comment: Can you post some of your code? it might be easier to trace what the issue is.

Comment: @d.datul1990 Okay. It isn't much though. Just a few lines in viewDidLoad()